# creating new column from columns whose name contains a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

For the columns with name containing a specific string `Time`, I would like to create a new column with the same name. I want for each item of Pax_cols (if there are more than one) to update the column with the sum with the column `Temp`.

```
data={'Run_Time':[60,20,30,45,70,100],'Temp':[10,20,30,50,60,100], 'Rest_Time':[5,5,5,5,5,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Pax_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Time' in col]
df[Pax_cols[0]]= df[Pax_cols[0]] + df["Temp"]
```

This is what I came up with, if Pax_cols has only one values, but it does not work.

Expected output:

```
data={'Run_Time':[70,40,60,95,130,200],'Temp':[10,20,30,50,60,100], 'Rest_Time':[15,25,35,55,65,105]}
```

Comment: can you provide the matching expected output for clarity?

Comment: @mozway I updated my question with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# get columns with "Time" in the name
cols = list(df.filter(like='Time'))
# ['Run_Time', 'Rest_Time']

# add the value of df['Temp']
df[cols] = df[cols].add(df['Temp'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
   Run_Time  Temp  Rest_Time
0        70    10         15
1        40    20         25
2        60    30         35
3        95    50         55
4       130    60         65
5       200   100        105
```